# File search in paths of environment variable "Path"

Tags: delphi

Is there any function (in Delphi) which can give out the full path and name of a file which is in one of paths in the environment variable Path, for example:

```
Fn: = FindFileEnv ('my.dll', EnvPath);
```

that returns for example

```
Fn = 'c:\windows\system32\my.dll'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, have earned! Function EnvFNS(Fn: string): string;
var SPPath: array[0..255] of char; PathPtr: PChar;
begin
if SearchPath(nil, PChar(Fn), nil, 255, SPPath, PathPtr)>0 then Result := StrPas(SPPath) else Result := Fn;
end;
//// Use: Showmessage(EnvFNS('notepad.exe'));